# Understanding GCC's alloca() alignment and seemingly missed optimization

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, x86-64, alloca

Consider the following toy example that allocates memory on the stack by means of the `alloca()` function:

```
#include <alloca.h>

void foo() {
    volatile int *p = alloca(4);
    *p = 7;
}
```

Compiling the function above using gcc 8.2 with `-O3` results in the following assembly code:

```
foo:
   pushq   %rbp
   movq    %rsp, %rbp
   subq    $16, %rsp
   leaq    15(%rsp), %rax
   andq    $-16, %rax
   movl    $7, (%rax)
   leave
   ret
```

Honestly, I would have expected a more compact assembly code.

---

#### 16-byte alignment for allocated memory

The instruction `andq $-16, %rax` in the code above results in `rax` containing the (only) *16-byte-aligned* address between the addresses `rsp` and `rsp + 15` (both inclusive).

This alignment enforcement is the first thing I don't understand: Why does `alloca()` align the allocated memory to a 16-byte boundary?

---

#### Possible missed optimization?

Let's consider anyway that we want the memory allocated by `alloca()` to be 16-byte aligned. Even so, in the assembly code above, keeping in mind that GCC assumes the stack to be aligned to a 16-byte boundary at the moment of performing the function call (i.e., `call foo`), if we pay attention to the status of the stack inside `foo()` *just after* pushing the `rbp` register:

```
Size          Stack          RSP mod 16      Description
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ------------------
        |       .        |
        |       .        | 
        |       .        |            
        ------------------........0          at "call foo" (stack 16-byte aligned)
8 bytes | return address |
        ------------------........8          at foo entry
8 bytes |   saved RBP    |
        ------------------........0  <-----  RSP is 16-byte aligned!!!
```

I think that by taking advantage of the *[red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing))* (i.e., no need to modify `rsp`) and the fact that `rsp` already contains a *16-byte aligned address*, the following code could be used instead:

```
foo:
   pushq   %rbp
   movq    %rsp, %rbp
   movl    $7, -16(%rbp)
   leave
   ret
```

The address contained in the register `rbp` is 16-byte aligned, therefore `rbp - 16` will also be aligned to a 16-byte boundary.

Even better, the creation of the new stack frame can be optimized away, since `rsp` is not modified:

```
foo:
   movl    $7, -8(%rsp)
   ret
```

Is this just a missed optimization or I am missing something else here?

Comment: Running on macOS? The macOS ABI requires 16 bytes stack alignment...

Comment: @Macmade: That requirement applies before a `call`.  There's no requirement that functions keep RSP 16-byte aligned *at all times*.  If gcc has to adjust RSP for anything, it will make it 16-byte aligned, but if it can just use the red-zone for locals it will leave RSP untouched (other than possible push/pop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x86-64 System V ABI requires VLAs (C99 Variable Length Arrays) to be 16-byte aligned, same for automatic / static arrays that are >= 16 bytes.

It looks like gcc is treating `alloca` as a VLA, and failing to do constant-propagation into an `alloca` that only runs once per function call.  (Or that it internally uses `alloca` for VLAs.)

A generic `alloca` / VLA can't use the red-zone, in case the runtime value is larger than 128 bytes.  GCC also makes a stack frame with RBP instead of saving the allocation size and doing an `add rsp, rdx` later.

**So the asm looks exactly like what it would if the size was a function arg or other runtime variable instead of a constant.**  That's what led me to this conclusion.

---

Also `alignof(maxalign_t) == 16` , but `alloca` and `malloc` can satisfy the requirement to return memory usable for any object without 16-byte alignment for objects smaller than 16 bytes.  None of the standard types have alignment requirements *wider* than their size in x86-64 SysV.

---

You're right, it should be able to optimize it to this:

```
void foo() {
    alignas(16) int dummy[1];
    volatile int *p = dummy;   // alloca(4)
    *p = 7;
}
```

and compile it to the `movl    $7, -8(%rsp)` ; `ret` you suggested.

The `alignas(16)` might be optional here for alloca.

---

If you *really* need gcc to emit better code when constant propagation makes the arg to `alloca` a compile-time constant, you could consider simply *using* a VLA in the first place.  GNU C++ supports C99-style VLAs in C++ mode, but ISO C++ (and MSVC) don't.

Or possibly use `if(__builtin_constant_p(size)) { VLA version } else { alloca version }`, but scoping of VLAs means you can't return a VLA from the scope of an `if` that detects that we're being inlined with a compile-time constant `size`.  So you'd have to duplicate the code that needs the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

This is (partially) missed optimization in gcc. Clang does it as expected.

I said partially because if you know you will be using gcc you can use builtin functions (use conditional compilation for gcc and other compilers to have portable code).

**[`__builtin_alloca_with_align`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)** is your friend **;)**

Here is an example (changed so the compiler will not reduce function call to single ret):

```
#include <alloca.h>

volatile int* p;

void foo() 
{
    p = alloca(4) ;
    *p = 7;
}

void zoo() 
{
    // aligment is 16 bits, not bytes
    p = __builtin_alloca_with_align(4,16) ;
    *p = 7;
}

int main()
{
  foo();
  zoo();
}
```

Disassembled code (with `objdump -d -w --insn-width=12 -M intel`)

Clang will produce the following code (`clang -O3 test.c`) - both functions look alike

```
0000000000400480 <foo>:
  400480:       48 8d 44 24 f8                          lea    rax,[rsp-0x8]
  400485:       48 89 05 a4 0b 20 00                    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200ba4],rax        # 601030 <p>
  40048c:       c7 44 24 f8 07 00 00 00                 mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x8],0x7
  400494:       c3                                      ret    

00000000004004a0 <zoo>:
  4004a0:       48 8d 44 24 fc                          lea    rax,[rsp-0x4]
  4004a5:       48 89 05 84 0b 20 00                    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200b84],rax        # 601030 <p>
  4004ac:       c7 44 24 fc 07 00 00 00                 mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x4],0x7
  4004b4:       c3                                      ret
```

GCC this one (`gcc -g -O3 -fno-stack-protector`)

```
0000000000000620 <foo>:
 620:   55                                      push   rbp
 621:   48 89 e5                                mov    rbp,rsp
 624:   48 83 ec 20                             sub    rsp,0x20
 628:   48 8d 44 24 0f                          lea    rax,[rsp+0xf]
 62d:   48 83 e0 f0                             and    rax,0xfffffffffffffff0
 631:   48 89 05 e0 09 20 00                    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2009e0],rax        # 201018 <p>
 638:   c7 00 07 00 00 00                       mov    DWORD PTR [rax],0x7
 63e:   c9                                      leave  
 63f:   c3                                      ret    

0000000000000640 <zoo>:
 640:   48 8d 44 24 fc                          lea    rax,[rsp-0x4]
 645:   c7 44 24 fc 07 00 00 00                 mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x4],0x7
 64d:   48 89 05 c4 09 20 00                    mov    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2009c4],rax        # 201018 <p>
 654:   c3                                      ret
```

As you can see zoo now looks like expected and similar to clang code.